# Taking a Form and saving it into a model

Tags: django, forms, models

I got this form working Ok but i can't figure out how to save it to the database via the model i know this is a semantic question that i can't figure out Please Help. I'm using django  The error is

```
 D = Donation(user=request.user,name=form.cleaned_data['name'],description=cd['descri‌​ption']) D.save()


views.py
    def donate(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DonationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                D = Donation(user=request.user,name=form.cleaned_data['name'],description=cd['description'])
                D.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/test/')
        else:
            form =DonationForm()
        return render_to_response('addaDonation.html',{'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

`
Donation is my Model and i need to get the information from my form into the Donation Model so i can D.save

```
class DonationForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=3000)
    towards = forms.CharField()
    #image = forms.ImageField()

class Donation (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    towards = models.ForeignKey(NonProfit)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d')
```

The error I get is 
(1054, "Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'")

```
Request information

GET
No GET data
POST
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken u'nXGN4gdZwk2qxNpP9YIXzvNQI7lKQe5r'
towards u'this'
name    u'this'
description u'that'
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: I get an error Unknown column 'name' in field list.  I know the error is in my views.py file D = Donation(user=request.user,name=form.cleaned_data['name'],description=cd['description'])
                D.save()       I just don't know the semantics to get it right and i can't find an example of form to model in django

Comment: That error has nothing to do with your form code. It's because you added the name field after creating the original dB table. Drop the table and run syncdb again. And the docs for model forms are clearly indexed from the documentation. Index as "Forms for models".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your form class to the following;

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
class DonationForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        class = Donation
        exclude = ("user", )

    def save(self, user):
        donation = super(DonationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        donation.user = user
        donation.save()
        return donation
```

Then you should be able to change the view.py to the following;

```
def donate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DonationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/test/')
    else:
        form = DonationForm()
    return render_to_response('addaDonation.html',{'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

See official documentation [Creating forms from Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: I did read the documentation and I tried to do it the above way so that it would NOT give me a drop down of the users.  I want the form and model to save the registered user.  This works but I need the form to ommit the user and save the registered user to the db

Comment: add users to the exclude list then

    exclude = ("image", "user", )

Comment: Ok if I add the user to the exclude list will it still save the registered user to the database, And I want the Image to be on the form I just commented it out here because there was more coding for it to work.  I took out the exclude of the image and put in the user but the form validation is not letting me upload an image even though there is a form field for it

Comment: The save method in the form handles the user and makes sure it gets saved to the database. There are a few more steps required with an image. Make sure you have the correct encoding for the form (enctype="multipart/form-data") and that you are passing in  request.FILES to the form.

Comment: I still get Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' and I did syncdb

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16320/discussion-between-reinbach-and-klanestro)